# dynamic key in JSON file (used by backbone.js models for example...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, model, backbone.js

I am trying to create a backbone.js model with dynamic keys but can't seem to get it done right.

Here's my model:

```
window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    myDynamicVar : "country",
    urlRoot: "api/myModel",
    defaults: {
        "id": null,
        this.myDynamicVar : "USA",
        "country":  {
            "route":"test/test/test",
            "class":".usa2",
            "txt":"USA 2"
        },  
        "region":  "California",
        "year":  "",
        "description":  "",
        "picture":  ""
      }
});
```

Here I am trying to have myDynamicVar replaced by its content in my model.
Any thought how I could get this done?
Thanks in advance,
Jimmy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do that directly; the left side of the ":" in an object literal must be a constant. What you can do is this:

```
window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    myDynamicVar : "country",
    urlRoot: "api/myModel",
    defaults: function(fieldName) {
      var value = {
        "id": null,
        "country":  {
            "route":"test/test/test",
            "class":".usa2",
            "txt":"USA 2"
        },  
        "region":  "California",
        "year":  "",
        "description":  "",
        "picture":  ""
      };
      value[fieldName] = "USA";
      return value;
    }(this.myDynamicVar)
});
```

*edit* — ah, I just noticed that "myDynamicVar" itself is part of the outer object.  There's no way to refer to it with `this` in such a way, so if that's what you're trying to do the code would be different:

```
window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend(function() {
  var value = {
    myDynamicVar : "country",
    urlRoot: "api/myModel",
    defaults: {
        "id": null,
        "country":  {
            "route":"test/test/test",
            "class":".usa2",
            "txt":"USA 2"
        },  
        "region":  "California",
        "year":  "",
        "description":  "",
        "picture":  ""
      }
   };

   value.defaults.[value.myDynamicVar] = "USA";
   return value;
}());
```

If you want `myDynamicVar` *itself* to be dynamic, then you could pass it in as a parameter:

```
window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend(function(whichProperty) {
  var value = {
    myDynamicVar : "country",
    urlRoot: "api/myModel",
    defaults: {
        "id": null,
        "country":  {
            "route":"test/test/test",
            "class":".usa2",
            "txt":"USA 2"
        },  
        "region":  "California",
        "year":  "",
        "description":  "",
        "picture":  ""
      }
   };

   value.defaults.[value[whichProperty]] = "USA";
   return value;
}("myDynamicVar"));
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're asking. One thing to note is that `this` in the above is whatever it is at the beginning of the `window.MyModel` assignment statement, and in particularly it will **not** be the object that's being constructed as the argument to `Model.extend()`.  I just used that because it was in the OP.

Comment: Thanks Pointy for your solution. It is not an easy way though but there is no other way to do it and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a variable in defining the object key. You can try something like this.

```
window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    myDynamicVar : "country",
    urlRoot: "api/myModel",
    defaults: {
        "id": null,
        "country":  {
            "route":"test/test/test",
            "class":".usa2",
            "txt":"USA 2"
        },  
        "region":  "California",
        "year":  "",
        "description":  "",
        "picture":  ""
      }
});

window.MyModel.defaults[this.myDynamicVar] = "USA";
```